# why was my comment erased?

Tags: discussion, comments, deleted-comments

Why was the comment "none of this provides a clear factual answer to the question" to the answer [here](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/32261/13162) erased?  It does fit.

Answer (score 6):

Your comment was:

> I just want to point out, for the sake of saving @indigochild some work, that "none of this provides a clear factual answer to the question".

Given that your [response](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/32260/was-any-official-explanation-provided-for-trump-defending-russia-over-fbi/32261#comment120859_32268) to [indigochild's comment](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/32260/was-any-official-explanation-provided-for-trump-defending-russia-over-fbi/32261#comment120848_32268) in your answer was not particularly friendly, I read your comment as snarky and removed it.

In any case, comments are ephemeral. Don't get overly attached to them, they may get removed at any time. Especially if they were posted for any reason other than to ask for clarifications.